# Badge for addressing yourself in a comment

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, badge-request

What do you do when you've made a comment, but much later realize it wasn't such a good idea after all? If it was someone else's comment, you'd comment on it, addressing whoever it was. So if it's your comment, I guess you address yourself.

Seems a bit silly, but makes logical sense. So it got me thinking, "Hey, there should be a badge for that!" (Badges are like apps in this sense.) I'm not sure what it would be called, maybe **split personality** - something not too serious, in any case. :-)

Comment: So I should get a badge for realizing I was wrong?

Comment: If *that's* the case, what about the [Disciplined](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/37/disciplined) badge?

Comment: There are quite few dialogs-with-self to be found, resulting from merged accounts (sock puppets).

Comment: @Makoto, [Disciplined](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/37/disciplined) only applies when post got score of >=3

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> What do you do when you've made a comment, but much later realize it
>   wasn't such a good idea after all?

Delete it...if it's not going to be of any use to anyone, then it may go the way of the `/dev/null`.  Certainly doesn't warrant a badge.

Comment: I was thinking of the case where other comments refer to the comment, so and deleting it would make what someone else said confusing. Otherwise, I concur with deletion, as it is that much less for readers to wade through. The badge idea was a bit of silliness. I just found a bit of humor in the concept of referring to yourself with a comment.